# Recursion in C function type with return

Tags: c, recursion

This is a quick question, I did a search but couldn't find anything that answered my question.

When doing a recursive function in C do you need to have a return even when using a void function?

Eg:

```
    void addToLL(structA_ptr new, structA_ptr cur) {
        if (cur->next == NULL) {
             cur->next = new;
        } else {
             addToLL(new, cur->next);
        }
    }
```

Would I need to put a return keyword before the call to the function?
I know that if the function would return something, like searching for something in the LL it would need a return statement.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @gbacon: What happened when hew tried it was that it appeared to work, but he wasn't 100% sure he'd fully understood what was going on, so he quite rightly thought he'd ask the experts at StackOverflow about it.

Comment: If you were thinking whether you should have "return addToLL(new, cur->next);" inside the function: no, you shouldn't: it will be an error because your "addToLL" function returns nothing, so returning "addToLL" isn't allowed inside the function body.

Answer (score 9):

No, you don't need it.

**Long answer**:
Your recursive function is executed like any other and if doesn't encounter a recursive call, it is simply terminated. You don't need an explicit return. You **can** use if you want to exit the function prematurely.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for a `return` statement in this case, but only because the function doesn't do anything after the recursive call.

If you'd had this:

```
void addToLL(structA_ptr new, structA_ptr cur) {
    if (cur->next == NULL) {
         cur->next = new;
    } else {
         addToLL(new, cur->next);
    }

    someOtherCode();
}
```

then you'd need to insert a `return;` statement after the call to `addToLL()` if you didn't want `someOtherCode()` to be called after `addToLL()` returned.

Comment: "The function doesn't do anything after the recursive call"? Not on the way down maybe, but how about on the way up?

Answer (score 0):

Returning values from functions isn't a prerequisite for recursion - in any language. So, no.

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a style issue. Some people consider ending a void function without a return keyword a faux-pas, others don't care. This really isn't recursion specific, though.

Answer (score 0):

When your function ends, it implicitly returns, so there is no need to call the return instruction.

[Value Add]
When functions are added returned in a program, the functions local variables and arguments are removed and return values are made available to the calling function, and execution resumes at the calling position.
When "void" functions are returned , they simply clean up arguments and local variables, and don't need to worry about moving return values to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a return type.

A recursive function is still useful without a return type because it could for example print values, calculate things by pointer parameter, or do a variety of other things.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your example code is a good example of a recursive function than can easily be converted to a loop making less strain on the stack when operating on a very long linked-list.

```
void addToLL(structA_ptr new, structA_ptr cur) {
    while (cur->next)
        cur = cur->next;
    cur->next = new;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a function with return type of `void` the only reason to use an explicit `return` statement would be if you wanted to exit function prematurely.